# How to forward traffic to another dns by port

Tags: networking, dns

In order for my app to work for example, it needs to communicate with 3 different url:port. Lets say:

`host1.com:1111`

`host2.com:1234`

`host3.com:1234`

(Same port for 2 hosts)

What i want is to use a single url, and the route will be betterment by the port:

`fathost.com:1111 --> host1.com:1111`

`fathost.com:2222 --> host2.com:1234`

`fathost.com:3333 --> host3.com:1234`

(Port 2222 is redirected to 1234 on host2,
Port 3333 is redirected to 1234 on host3)

Keep in mind that the app is run on a clients machine, so changing iptables is not possible.

Tried a loadbalancer but it can only return a redirect (status code 302,301) and i need it to transfer the request.
Tried solve it with Dns records (srv), but no luck

Any ideas? (Cloud services also a possible option)

Thanks for the help

**UPDATE:**
Because the app is run on a clients machine, Im asking the client to allow traffic from all 3 hosts (`host1, host2, host3`), what I want is to only allow traffic from 1 host `fasthost.com` (that will probably will have a static ip)

Comment: Do you have control over fathost.com server? What kind of webserver/appserver is running there?

Comment: I can make `fathost.com` to point to a fresh new linux machine and run whats needed

Comment: Then you only need some kind  reverse proxy running there (for example [nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) or [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html))